# Get list of Class names in package

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

Is there any way I can get a list of all the classes in a particular package?

I know getDefinitionByName, getQualifiedClassName, and getQualifiedSuperclassName in [flash.utils](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html) can find me a class, but I can't find anyway to find all the classes in a package at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ActionScript reflection is limited to the three functions you mentioned and `flash.utils.describeType(object:*)`.