# Flex Mobile & PHP (Remote) Development

Tags: php, apache-flex, mobile, adobe

I'm having some trouble with the services. We're wanting to put the PHP services on a website, and access them remotely with the Flex mobile application, and project type is a Flex Mobile & PHP Project.

I was wondering if it were possible to do this? To be able to use the services' scripts remotely from the Flex Mobile application? Thanks!

To clarify... right now I'm trying to test something out, and I'm just getting an AsyncToken object, and I'm not sure if I'm doing anything correctly. I basically want to be able to execute the services like in those basic Employee tutorials, except I want the PHP scripts on my website where the Flex Mobile application will access them remotely.

Any suggestions on going about this? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify from all the negatives I've received, I've looked on here for solutions and none of them resolved my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, what you need is a remoting bridge to serialize object form and to PHP and ActionScript 3. Look for AMFPHP here http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/

Comment: Regarding your edit to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2879567/229044): Editing is for *fixing* answers, not changing their meaning entirely. If you have a *different* answer, submit it as an answer. Don't edit somebody else's answer to reflect your opinion.