# Listing all public variables/instances in a swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok, I've been working with this issue for a couple of days now and I am alsmost losing it.

So this is the scenario:

I have a host that loads swf files, and it has a function that is supposed to return all text fields that is present in the swf as metadata to be able to build an interface to communicate with the swf.

So I've tried describeType which works fine for all instances that are placed directly on the stage, but as soon as they reside inside a movieclip the are not listed. The reference to the movie clip is listed but since the custom text field is a dynamic variable it is not listed in the movie clip class and since it might not yet be instantiated when the function is called I cannot make a describeType on the Object.

I have tried the as3commons reflect and bytecode classes without success, and also the as3swf which lists them but in a very unusable way.

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Imagine there is an SWF that creates a new instance of `TextField` upon mouse click and places it on the stage somewhere. (And maybe some are created in the constructor) How many text fields you want to be returned by your function? They are not yet present, but they exist at runtime, and might be needed for something within it. I believe the correct universal solution is impossible, but approximations exist. You can also run the display list of that SWF to find out where are the nested text fields.

Comment: I want to return all the instance names of future instances that is places anywhere in the timeline. Not dynamically (with code) instantiated objects, I understand that is inpossible. I know the information is inside the swf since I can find it with as3swf but i cannot get them using describeType. Not until the object is instantiated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of Class names in package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878127/get-list-of-class-names-in-package)